# Return list of values from list inside json

Tags: python, json, list

I have a json and I'd like to get only specific values into a list. I can do this just fine iterating through, but I'm wondering if there's an easy one-liner list comprehension method to do this. Suppose I have a json:

```
{
    "results": {
        "types": 
        [
            {
                "ID": 1
                "field": [
                    {
                        "type": "date",
                        "field": "PrjDate"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "date",
                        "field": "ComplDate"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like to get all of the `field` values into a single list:

```
fieldsList = ['PrjDate', 'ComplDate']
```

I can do this easily with

```
for types in myjson['results']['types']:
    fieldsList = []
    for fields in types['field']:
        fieldsList.append(fields['field'])
```

But that seems unnecessarily clunky, is there an easy one-liner list comprehension method I can use here?

Comment: Can you have more than one element in `types: [...]`?

Comment: @marekful yes there will usually be more than one element in there. See edit, there was an ID field I forgot to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
myfields = [fields['field'] for types in myjson['results']['types'] for fields in types['field']]
```